# Passing string values from asynctask to arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask

Currently I am looking for a way to pass several **private decalared** string values (fac_naam, fac_straat, fac_post, etc..) to an arraylist.
The arraylist is being created by a method *SetStandardGroups* and the **collected values** from asynctask should be passed to the *child_2* value.
Now the child_2 values are always empty as they are newly created.
Is there a way to do this?

Thank you upfront.

Make the calls:

> ```
> @Override
> public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
>
>     // get the listview
>     ExpandList = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.expListView);
>
>     // execute AsyncTask
>     new FetchWebsiteData().execute();
>
>     // preparing list data
>     ExpListItems = SetStandardGroups();
>
>     ExpAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this.getActivity(), ExpListItems);
>
>     // setting list adapter
>     ExpandList.setAdapter(ExpAdapter);
>     return rootView;
> }
> ```

Method SetStandardGroups:

> ```
> private ArrayList<Group> SetStandardGroups() {
>
>     String headers[] = {"Factuurgegevens", "Contactgegevens", "Betalingsgegevens",
>             "MijnZiggo Mobiel account", "Wachtwoord"};
>
>     String child_1[] = {"Naam", "Straat en huisnummer", "Postcode en woonplaats", "Telefoonummer",
>             "E-mail", "Rekeningnummer", "Naam rekeninghouder", "Gebruikersnaam", "Wachtwoord"};
>
>     String child_2[] = {fac_naam, fac_straat, fac_post, con_tel,
>             con_email, betaal_reknr, betaal_houd, zig_gebruiker, zig_wacht};
>
>     ArrayList<Group> list = new ArrayList<Group>();
>
>     ArrayList<Child> ch_list; 
>     }
>     return list;
> }
> ```

The AsyncTask in which the values are being set:

> ```
> private class FetchWebsiteData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onPreExecute() {
>         super.onPreExecute();
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected Void doInBackground(Void... result) {
>         InputStream is = null;
>         try {
>             is = MainActivity.mContext.getAssets().open("Mobiel.html");
>
>             Document doc = Jsoup.parse(is, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");
>             // Get the html document title
>             Elements els = doc.select("span[class=item-value pull-right]");
>             // get the values and set them
>             if (els.size() > 0) {
>                 fac_naam = els.get(0).text();
>                 fac_straat = els.get(1).text();
>                 fac_post = els.get(2).text();
>                 con_tel = els.get(3).text();
>                 con_email = els.get(4).text();
>                 betaal_reknr = els.get(5).text();
>                 betaal_houd = els.get(6).text();
>                 zig_gebruiker = els.get(7).text();
>                 zig_wacht = els.get(8).text();
>             }
>             else // do something
>
>         } catch (IOException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>
>         return null;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
>
>    }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got yourself a concurrency issue.  When you do:

```
// execute AsyncTask
new FetchWebsiteData().execute();

// preparing list data
ExpListItems = SetStandardGroups();
```

The AsyncTask has likely not finished executing before SetStandardGroups() is called and as such the variables are still null.  You will need to change it so that the adapter code is called after the AsyncTask has finished.  I'd make a new method something like:

```
private void setupAdapter() {

    // preparing list data
    ExpListItems = SetStandardGroups();

    ExpAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this.getActivity(), ExpListItems);

    // setting list adapter
    ExpandList.setAdapter(ExpAdapter);
}
```

And then in the onPostExecute() method of your AsyncTask call the new method:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    setupAdapter();
}
```